# What kind of database connecting string is needed to run application in different computers

Tags: c#, database, c#-4.0

I am learning c# and sql database. I have a database management system developed in c#.net.

My database connection string is:

> string _ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Promming Codes\OOP2 (C#)Programs\C# Database\MMS\MMS\MMSdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

It works on my PC very fine, but when I try to install the setup file to my friends PC, the connection string cannot be found. How can i overcome this kind of problems?

Comment: Has your friend installed SQL Express ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access the database from your friend's computer and both of you are on the same network then you need to modify your connection string. Your current connection string is pointing to local machine, you need it to point to your machine (Which is acting like a server). Your connection string in that case should be :

> string _ConnectionString = @"DataSource=yourmachineaddress\SQLEXPRESS;
>   AttachDbFilename=E:\Promming Codes\OOP2 (C#)Programs\C#
>   database\MMS\MMS\MMSdatabase.mdf; Integrated Security=True;User
>   Instance=True";

where your machine address could be your machine name. You may also enable remote access on your sql server. [How to enable Remote Connection in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

If you and your friend are not on the same network and you need to install a separate instance of the application then you have to install SQL Express on your friend's computer. Restore the database there and create connection string according to that particular machine setting. For building connection string check [Connection strings for SQL Server 2008](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Comment: Thanks brother Habib, I want to install a setup file of my management system on my friend's computer.I don't want to give him the source code to modify the connection string.